# Comparing ints gives strange results

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get my head around usual arithmetic conversions and tried to test:

```
(static_cast<unsigned char>(std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()) > static_cast<signed char>(-1))
```

this evaluates to true, which is ok, but according to Arithmetic conversion it should result in false (last bullet):

> > Integral promotions are performed on the operands as follows:
>
> If either operand is of type unsigned long, the other operand is
>   converted to type unsigned long.
>
> If preceding condition not met, and if either operand is of type long
>   and the other of type unsigned int, both operands are converted to
>   type unsigned long.
>
> If the preceding two conditions are not met, and if either operand is
>   of type long, the other operand is converted to type long.
>
> If the preceding three conditions are not met, and if either operand
>   is of type unsigned int, the other operand is converted to type
>   unsigned int.
>
> If none of the preceding conditions are met, both operands are
>   converted to type int.

The last bullet says that if none of the other conditions are met both operands will be convered to type int. Following this unsigned char(max_char) will have bit pattern filled with ones only and signed char(-1) will have bit patterns filled with ones only. This would mean 1 > 1 == false, yet I'm getting the true. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You're right that the last bullet is the one that is used, so both operands are converted to type `int`.  The left-hand side is `(unsigned char)255`, and the right-hand side is `(signed char)-1`.  Since both 255 and -1 are representable as an `int`, they get converted into `(int)255` and `(int)-1` respectively, and since 255 is greater than -1, it returns `true`.

Comment: #Adam This confuses me even more ;).255 as int has pattern 0000  ... 1111 1111 and -1 is filled with just ones. How is this possible that 0000 ... 1111 1111 is greater than 1111 ... 1111 1111 ?

Comment: @smallB: Because they are *signed* integers.  Regardless of how they're represented (two's complement, one's complement, or sign-magnitude), what matters is the *numeric* value.  In ordinary arithmetic, 255 is always a greater value than -1.

Comment: #Adam so their type is actually taken into account? I thought only bit pattern is compared, but it looks like type of those operands plays significant part, am I right?